# Picture download

Tags: 16.04

I need to know how to rip photos off of my 16.04 Ubuntu computer onto a DVD. I've searched through the entire computer and could not find a way to do this, so please help.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install brasero` or `sudo apt install k3b`, or search for these packages in the software centre (Discover app)

Answer (score 1):

K3b is an excellent choice for this type of project. It's available in the universe repository. To enable the universe repository, open Software & Updates and check the second box from the top on the first tab. Then you can install K3b either through the Software Center of via a terminal with the command `sudo apt install k3b`

On the opening screen choose New Data Project, then navigate to the location where you keep your photos and drag and drop individual photos and or entire folders from the top window to the bottom window. you can select multiples with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys. K3b will even warn you if you exceed the capacity of the disk as shown below.

[image: k3b]

When you've added what you want, simply insert a DVD and click the Burn button.